# Pulling a Letter Grade From an Excel Table Array

Tags: excel

I am wondering if there is an easier way to pull a letter grade out of an array then the current way i use with a bunch of Nested If statements.

My idea is If GPA (G1-G5) is in between B1:C12 Then return A1-A12. Picture 1 shows Raw Data, Picture 2 is the Desired Output.

[This is an example of the raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1E5c.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h250O.png)

Comment: Look into index/match `=INDEX($A$1:$A$12,MATCH(F1,$C$1:$C$12))`

Comment: That won't work here because I am trying to check if 3.2 is in between or equal to B1:C12 and then return the letter grade.

Comment: Sorry, Sort columns A:C on Column C in Ascending order and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the "higher" column, just use the "lower value" column and the letter grade column as your first two columns.  Sort them in ascending order so they're in A1:B12.

```
0.00, F
0.34, D-
0.68, D
1.01, D+
1.34, C-
1.68, C
2.01, C+
2.34, B-
2.68, B
3.01, B+
3.34, A-
3.68, A
```

Now if your grade is in (for example) cell D3, you can get the letter grade into cell E3 with...

```
=VLOOKUP(D3,A1:B12,2,TRUE)
```

This will return the second column value for the first number greater than or equal to the first column value.

Comment: You are a Genius and just made what I do 100 times more efficient thank you.